# Github Search API - Exclude certain topics

Tags: github-api, github-api-v3

According to the docs, I could use `-` to exclude certain things from the search API... I tested it and this works on the language field for example, but doesn't work on topics.
[According to the documentation:](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results)

> note
> cats stars:>10 -language:javascript matches repositories with the word "cats" that have more than 10 stars but are not written in JavaScript.

But if I want to search for `cats stars:>10 -topic:javascript` it doesn't work anymore, although I tested it and there are exactly 9 repositories that have `javascript` as a topic.
So

`cats stars:>10` returns 714 results

`cats stars:>10 -topic:javascript` returns 714 results (`-` doesn't work)
`cats stars:>10 +topic:javascript` returns 9 results

`cats stars:>10 -language:javascript` returns 602 results (`-` works as expected)
`cats stars:>10 +language:javascript` returns 112 results

Comment: I think this is a bug in the github search. I confirm this is not working for the topic search.

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround with GitHub CLI:

Replace: `ORG` with organization name.

Unix:

```
gh repo list ORG --json name,repositoryTopics --limit 200 --jq '.[] | select(.repositoryTopics//[] | all(.name != "unwanted-label-name"))' | sort
```

Windows:

```
gh repo list ORG --json name,repositoryTopics --limit 200 --jq ".[] | select(.repositoryTopics//[] | all(.name != """unwanted-label-name"""))" | sort
```

For GitHub enterprise, set environment variable before running commands:

```
GH_HOST=your.github.enterprise.company.host
```