# In Github's GraphQL API how to get repositories that do not have a particular repositoryTopic?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

With Github's GraphQL API I recently found "[Github API: Getting topics of a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259946/github-api-getting-topics-of-a-github-repository)" that mentions you can get a count of topics:

```
{
  repository(owner: "twbs", name: "bootstrap") {
    repositoryTopics(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          topic {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but in the docs and in my search I'm not finding how I can query repositories that do not contain the topic `template`, example:

```
query ($github_org: String!, $repo_count: Int!) {
  organization(login: $github_org) {
    repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy: PUBLIC, isFork: false) {
      nodes {
        id
        name
        openGraphImageUrl
        createdAt
        stargazerCount
        url
        description
        repositoryTopics(first: 10, after: "template") {
          edges {
            node {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is the correct implementation to use `after`? In Github's GraphQL API how to exclude a repository if it contains a certain topic?

Comment: Hey. This is not the correct use of `after`. The `after` parameter is used to pass the cursor you want to get results "after". You can get the cursors of the nodes in the page object.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that with the [organization](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/queries#organization) query you cannot do that kind of repository filtering.

Instead, you can use the [search](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/queries#searchresultitemconnection) query with something like this:

```
query ($repo_count: Int!) {
  search (first: $repo_count,
          type: REPOSITORY,
          query: "org:my-organization topic:my-topic") {
    nodes {
      ... on Repository {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query searches for all repositories within a given organization that have a given topic.

But you were looking for the repositories **without** a topic, in theory according [to the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results) you should be able to do that with `-topic:my-topic`. Unfortunately the negation on topic doesn't work, there seems to be [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554246/github-search-api-exclude-certain-topics). :-(